# In python how i convert a txt file in a xlsx and put in eache cell only the block of rows before "$" and the rest block in the other cell?

Tags: python

**For example i have:**

a
b
c
d
e$fghi
l
m
n
o

I want to have the first block (until the $) in one cell and the rest in the other one (and again if i have other blocks separated by $).

I used this code but it doesn't work (used csv):

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = '/MR/Others/prova.csv'
output_file = '/MR/Others/output.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='$')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Hi  - What is the output? No errors? Is the output file created? Does the file have errors opening? File is ok but is blank? I ran the code and it seems to do the needful. Issue opening the file as output file is xls and not xlsx, but ok otherwise

Comment: Thanks @Redox, i tried to explain the problem in the answer below

Comment: Hi @Marco - Are you saying that the data after `$` sign in any row should go to cell B1, then B2 and so on? Also, please move the information that you have in the answer into the question as this is not allowed. Please confirm on the first point and I will try to write code for the same

Comment: Thanks @Redox,I mean that everything before the "$" and after must be in the same column but in separate cells. Taking my cue from the input you wrote in your answer, in cell A1 I would like: "rr q3tbw4g
 t24t wgwg
qweq", in cell A2 instead "!%#%
ffwq r*&^
rqer " and so on.

Comment: Check the response below - the EDIT section has the updated code....

Comment: Hi @Redox i'm really grateful! the code is perfect and i understand! i will improve the code based on my next activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that should do what you need. Note that everything till the first `$` sign will be added to the first column (A). From there, it will move the next section to the second column (B). This will be done using a list, so there will not be any gaps, as you requested. For testing, I have used multiple rows with $ sign, it should work as well for a single row with $ sign as well. Note that this will work till the second $ sign only.

**Data** 4 rows with $ sign

```
rr   q3tbww4g
 t24t  wgwg
qweq$!%#%
ffwq r*&^
rqer $ 41
er34
f3r $ 42t 24t
a b c d e$fghi l m n o
```

**Code**

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = 'prova.csv'
output_file = 'Book1.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
myList = []
with open(input_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='$')
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        ws.cell(i+1,1).value = row[0] ## Move pre-$ into new workbook, column A
        if(len(row) > 1):             ## If there is a $, then add it to a list
            myList.append(row[1])

for i in range(len(myList)):          ## Once all rows with $ are collected, add it to column B
    ws.cell(i+1, 2).value = myList[i]
    
wb.save(output_file)
```

**Output excel**

[image]

**EDIT - Updated as per message from Marco**

Hi - As per your message, the code has been updated. The input data is as it was in my example above. The csv will be read into a long string, called `long_string` rather than a dataframe, then split into an array using `split('$')` and finally written to the output file. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = 'prova.csv'
output_file = 'Book1.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

long_string = ""
with open(input_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        long_string = long_string + ' '.join(row)
        
myarray = long_string.split('$')

for i in range(len(myarray)):
    ws.cell(1,i+1).value = myarray[i]
wb.save(output_file)
```

**Output excel**

[image]